# spacing from calculator package

Tags: spacing, calculations

I'm trying to include images and overlay them with their width and height info in mm. I save the image to a box and then use the calculator package to calculate the mm width and height of that box. Then I use a picture environment to place the image and, on top of it, a fcolorbox with the measurements.

What happens is that I get additional spacing before the picture environment, but only when using the commands from the calculator package. Is there a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my example, with a \rule as a dummy for the image; page 1 with calculated measurements, page 2 with measurements entered manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{calculator}
\newsavebox{\tmpboxa}%
\begin{document}\noindent
    \savebox{\tmpboxa}{\rule{\textwidth}{50mm}}% This is where the image will be includegraphicsed
    \LENGTHDIVIDE{\wd\tmpboxa}{1mm}{\breite}%
    \ROUND[2]{\breite}{\Breite}%
    \LENGTHDIVIDE{\ht\tmpboxa}{1mm}{\hoehe}%
    \ROUND[2]{\hoehe}{\Hoehe}%
    \begin{picture}(\breite mm, \hoehe mm)%
        \put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\usebox{\tmpboxa}}}%
        \put(1mm,1mm){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\fcolorbox{black}{black!15}{\strut \Breite\,mm $\times$ \Hoehe\,mm}}}%
    \end{picture}%  
    \\
    \blindtext
    \clearpage\noindent
    \savebox{\tmpboxa}{%
        \rule{\textwidth}{50mm}%
    }%
    \begin{picture}(\textwidth, 50mm)%
        \put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\usebox{\tmpboxa}}}%
        \put(1mm,1mm){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\fcolorbox{black}{black!15}{\strut 121.25\,mm $\times$ 50\,mm}}}%
    \end{picture}%
    \\
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
    \savebox{\tmpboxa}{\rule{\textwidth}{50mm}}% This is where the image will be includegraphicsed
\setbox0\hbox{\LENGTHDIVIDE{\wd\tmpboxa}{1mm}{\breite}%
    \ROUND[2]{\breite}{\Breite}%
    \LENGTHDIVIDE{\ht\tmpboxa}{1mm}{\hoehe}%
    \ROUND[2]{\hoehe}{\Hoehe}}\showoutput\showbox0
```

you'll see

```
> \box0=
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x6.66666
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
```

so as you suspected these commands are adding two spaces (probably missing `%` at ends of lines in its code). If you want to use them a simple workaround would be to move the `\noindent` to just before `\begin{picture}` so that the calculations happen in vertical mode where spaces are ignored.

The package is clearly not expecting calculations in horizontal mode, it would need dozens of `%` and `\relax` adding to protect against white space, but in this case you can just fix `\LENGTHDIVIDE` and the two spaces go:

Add this after loading the package.

```
\makeatletter
\def\LENGTHDIVIDE#1#2#3{%
       \begingroup
       \cctr@lengtha=#1\relax
       \cctr@lengthb=#2\relax
       \edef\cctr@tempa{\expandafter\strip@pt\cctr@lengtha}%
       \edef\cctr@tempb{\expandafter\strip@pt\cctr@lengthb}%
       \DIVIDE{\cctr@tempa}{\cctr@tempb}{#3}%
       \@OUTPUTSOL{#3}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'll want the whole stuff inside a macro that will kind of replace `\includegraphics', and it will sometimes be called from within a wrapfigure environment. Guess I'll have to look for a different package to do the calculations with.

Comment: @Blackface updated with a fix (for this one command) It may be worth contacting the package maintainer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Most of the `\UPPERCASE` commands in `calculator` have `\ignorespaces` at their end; the author forgot to mask *several* end-of-lines where those commands aren't used. Also the `\@UPPERCASE` command were forgotten, so fixing the package is quite a mess.

Comment: Pity. @David's patch works fine for me and for now, but for the future: Is there a less messy alternative? Preferably documented, unlike fp? BTW, I also wrote a mail to the author.

Comment: Thank you, Blackface and David. 

I will try to find the parts of the package where unwanted spaces appears.